# What is the title of the werewolf chapter in "Three Hearts and Three Lions" by Poul Anderson?

Tags: three-hearts-and-three-lions

For a long time I have thought that the fantasy novel *Three Hearts and Three Lions* (1961) by Poul Anderson, and the mystery novel *Castle Skull* (1931) by John Dickson Carr had something in common.

I have believed that one of the chapters in *Castle Skull* and one of the chapters - obviously the werewolf one - in *Three Hearts and Three Lions* had the same title, or similar titles.  I remembered the title (or titles) as "In Fear of the Werewolf" or "Through Fear of the Werewolf", or something similar, which I think are really great titles.

Today I looked at a copy of *Castle Skull* and found that one of the chapters is titled "For Fear of the Werewolf___".  This chapter title seems to be the only one with quotation marks, so maybe it is a quotation of some kind.

So now I want to know if *Three Hearts and Three Lions* does have a chapter with such a title, and if anyone knows if "For Fear of the Werewolf___" is a quotation.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in Blaze's answer, the chapters in *Three Hearts and Three Lions* are simply numbered, not titled. However, there is a line near the beginning of Chapter Fourteen resembling the one you quoted:

> 'Are there any back doors?' Holger asked. The blood thudded in his temples. **He had no fear of the werewolf**, nor even any sense of strangeness. This was *right*: the work for which he had been born.
>
> <sub>*Three Hearts & Three Lions* by Poul Anderson</sub>

I pulled the quotation from [this preview](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Three_Hearts_Three_Lions/N-pXzIkzjpYC?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Answer (score 3):

I have two editions of "Three Hearts and Three Lions".  The 1961 Doubleday paper back and an ePub digital taken from I don't know what edition.  Neither have chapter titles, only chapter numbers.